# PHP File Uploading - No File Uploaded Error

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've created an image uploading form , using twitter bootstrap and the jansy extention, using the next code section:

```
     <form action="fileName.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
          <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
          <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="pic" id="pic"/></span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

on the fileName.php the following code is executed:

```
print_r($_FILES);
if($_FILES["pic"]["error"] > 0){ /*image uploading has failed*/
        echo "Error occured ".$_FILES["pic"]["error"];  
    }
else {
    echo "image was uploaded successfully";
}
```

and returns the next message :

```
Array ( [pic] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) Error occured 4
```

How come the file is not uploaded ? How could I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of file?

Comment: @Narek file size is 100KB

Comment: please try input type submit instead button.

Comment: @Praveenkalal , still not working

Comment: Have you tried setting error output on your page? Are the permissions on the required directories correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 4 means `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`, so no file has been posted. I'd say the problem is somewhere in your javascript code or the components you used. Is any JavaScript error thrown?

Try a simple

```
<form action="fileName.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="pic"> 
</form>
```

to see if it works without any JavaScript plugins.

Comment: first of all thanks for the answer. There is no JS error thrown and I'm using JANSY extention for twitter bootstrap